# Can't find variable: $ safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

[enter link description here](https://ctrlv.cz/JWzh)

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#responsecontainer").load("response.php");
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
$("#responsecontainer").load('response.php?randval ='+ Math.random());
}, 90000);
});
</script>
```

can you help me
site safari does not open

Comment: In the snippet you do not include jQuery or another library that uses `$`. Is there anything like this included in the "real" site?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you dont include library like jquery, or your library's directory is wrong

Comment: this is not an answer